# Bitbucket Commit Push History

Tags: git, bitbucket

I have been using bitbucket to manage our git repo. We have mainly two branches
**Master** and **Dev**.
Master branch is the one we use for Build using Jenkins.
One day we found out that Master branch contains an **older version** and was unable to figure out who pushed an older Master branch. 
We are able to get all the commits done to a branch but someone has pushed an older master branch. Is there a way to figure it out.

> (Usually all the commits are merged to Dev branch and Dev will be
>   merged to master upgrading the assembly and tagging)

Comment: There's always a way to figure it out, git is non-destructive by design so all the history is there for the asking. You probably have to formulate your question better in your mind and certainly have to here so that we have a chance of answering it.

Comment: @msw That being said, git *does* clean up orphaned commits after some time. I also don't believe it tracks pushes at all - that'd be something bitbucket would have to track

Comment: Also, googling 'bitbucket push history' yields [this](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/audit-logging-in-bitbucket-server-776640417.html)

Comment: @Rob: You are correct about the orphans, but I am trying to parse "pushed an older master" and failing. Even if I `--force` push an old commit, the commit log will show me as the dunderhead.

Comment: @msw The way I read it was that an older (or potentially a commit not even in master's history) was force pushed to the repository. The only information available via git would be the author of that commit - not the pusher, though if its not malicious it's likely they're the same person - but its not guaranteed